# Implicit UUID auto fields for primary keys in Django

Tags: django, django-models

By default, Django adds integer primary keys as Autofields. This is annoying for many purposes, but especially makes debugging more difficult (code may accidently refer to the wrong "id", but instead of creating a runtime error, this might work in "some" instances because the IDs are accidently the same).

I want either unique integers across all tables or UUIDs for primary key. I do not want to specify either explicitly, since I want to only use this for debugging (and switch back to integers in production).

This is not a new proposal, but all answers seem to say "this is not performant" (blinding flash of the obvious) or advise to use explicit UUID fields (I don't want to do this because it means changing my model EVERYWHERE, then having to change it back later). Is there a way how to achieve this?

The proposals I've looked at (none of which answer by question) can be found here: [Using a UUID as a primary key in Django models (generic relations impact)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936182/using-a-uuid-as-a-primary-key-in-django-models-generic-relations-impact) and [Django: Unique ID's across tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569441/django-unique-ids-across-tables) with an open ticket for this feature here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32577

Comment: It is possible but with some tricks. I think the main problem might be that the model sees an `AutoField` as something that translates to an `int`, in some libraries it makes a type on the fly for `MyModelPk`, that wraps the int into it, this also prevents adding two primary keys together, since that is non-sensical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A not very well known feature is that you can set the [**`DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std-setting-DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD) to specify the primary key used by all models, except stated differently in the model itself, or the app config. Now one of the problems is that Django currently does not like the idea very much to plug in a `UUIDField`, but we can "force" this by specifying our own with:

```
# app_name/fields.py

import uuid

from django.db.backends.base.operations import BaseDatabaseOperations
from django.db.models import AutoField, UUIDField

BaseDatabaseOperations.integer_field_ranges['UUIDField'] = (0, 0)


class UUIDAutoField(UUIDField, AutoField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('default', uuid.uuid4)
        kwargs.setdefault('editable', False)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then plug the `UUIDAutoField` as default field:

```
# settings.py

# …

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'app_name.fields.UUIDAutoField'
```

That being said, in my humble opinion, it was a bit of a misfeature to map an `AutoField` to an `int` and vice versa. One could make a separate type for each model like a `UserPk` class, that wraps an `int` and thus disables arithmetic on that field (since adding two `UserPk`s together makes not much sense), and introduce type chekcs such that if you filter on `User.objects.filter(pk=42)`, it errors if `42` is a simple `int`, or some primary key of another model. Haskell's [**`esqueleto`** <sup>[hackage]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto) follows this idea.

Comment: Ah, this is getting me further than ever before. I've set the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD to UUIDAutoField, which I guess is what you meant? What happens though is that for Django-internal data types, the UUIDs are used for primary keys (e.g., the django_migrations table now has a char(32) data type and looks like it's UUID4 content), but my own models still use integers as a primary key, even though the primary key is implicit. Why would that be?

Comment: @roughdog: the `AppConfig` can override the `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD`, so that might be why it still uses an `AutoField`?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for :

```
 id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Comment: This does nothing but change the id field on a model to use a UUID... this changes nothing about the default AutoField that django uses when no pkey is specified on a model.